# How to fix CORS error while using Models.Pointfield function of GeoDjango Framework?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, postgis, geodjango

User is required to click on the location in map using Pointfield. This is my code for models

```
    class Marker(models.Model):
    """A marker with name and location."""

    Market_Place_Name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    GPS_Location = models.PointField()
    Http_Location = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return string representation."""
        return self.name
```

I get error message saying the following and map doesn't load either as shown below:

[image: Error openlayers map that doesn't load]
[image: This is for user to click any location loaded on the map, but the map doesn't load only throws this error as shown below]

I've tried adding these following codes on setting.py of geodjango project, but nothing seems to work

```
INSTALLED_APPS = ['corsheaders']
MIDDLEWARE = ["corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware']
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
"http://localhost:8000",
"http://127.0.0.1:8000"]
```

Comment: Did you install corshearders, if not please install using `pip install django-cors-headers` and make `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
` Hope this helps

Comment: @y051 i did install cors header using pip and also `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True` has been changed to `CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True` but i already did try both, nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

It is an OSM problem, the resource you are trying to load (e.g. `https://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/3/6/5.png`) does not have the appropriate headers.

I had the same problem and ended up using the default [GeoModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/gis/admin/#geomodeladmin) model, which uses OpenLayers.

PS: In django 4.0 `OSMGeoAdmin` is deprecated in favor of [GISModelAdmin](https://PS:%20In%20django%204.0%20OSMGeoAdmin%20is%20deprecated%20in%20favor%20of%20GISModelAdmin.):

> class OSMGeoAdmin: A subclass of GeoModelAdmin that uses a Spherical Mercator projection with OpenStreetMap street data tiles. Deprecated since version 4.0: This class is deprecated. Use GISModelAdmin instead.